# from scalawithcats book: value asRight is not a member of type parameter A

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, cats-effect

I'm reading the "scala with cats" book. On page 339, I copied the example code but run with the 'value asRight is not a member of type parameter A' error.

My code is as follow, which is exactly the same with the book

```
import cats.Semigroup
import cats.instances.list._
import cats.syntax.either._
import cats.syntax.semigroup._

/**
 * This one is called implementation check and it is better
 *
 * @tparam E An template Error Type
 * @tparam A Template Data Type
 */
sealed trait Check[E, A] {
  import Check._

  def and(that: Check[E, A]): Check[E, A] =
    And(this, that)

  def apply(a: A)(implicit s: Semigroup[E]): Either[E, A] =
    this match {
      case Pure(f)          => f(a)
      case And(left, right) =>
        (left(a), right(a)) match {
          case (Right(a), Right(_)) => a.asRight
          case (Right(_), Left(e))  => e.asLeft
          case (Left(e), Right(_))  => e.asLeft
          case (Left(e1), Left(e2)) => (e1 |+| e2).asLeft
        }
    }
}

object Check {
  final case class And[E, A](left: Check[E, A], right: Check[E, A]) extends Check[E, A]

  final case class Pure[E, A](func: A => Either[E, A]) extends Check[E, A]

  def pure[E, A](f: A => Either[E, A]): Check[E, A] = Pure(f)

}

val a: Check[List[String], Int] =
  Check.pure {
    v =>
      if (v > 2) v.asRight
      else List ("Must be > 2").asLeft
  }

val b: Check[List[String], Int] =
  Check.pure {
    v =>
      if (v < - 2) v.asRight
      else List ("Must be < -2").asLeft
  }

val check: Check[List[String], Int] = a and b
check(5)
check(-10)
```

I put the above code in the script file 'check.sc' and my cat dependency is:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "2.1.0"
```

When I use IDEA to run the snippet, it returns me

```
value asRight is not a member of type parameter A
case (Right(a), Right(_)) => a.asRight
```

Is that IDEA bug or something? Because if I paste the code into a scala file and run with a main function, it didn't complain anymore.

Below is correct:

```
package org.scala.ch10

import cats.Semigroup
import cats.instances.list._
import cats.syntax.either._
import cats.syntax.semigroup._

/**
 * This one is called implementation check and it is better
 *
 * @tparam E An template Error Type
 * @tparam A Template Data Type
 */
sealed trait CheckADT[E, A] {
  import CheckADT._

  def and(that: CheckADT[E, A]): CheckADT[E, A] =
    And(this, that)

  def apply(a: A)(implicit s: Semigroup[E]): Either[E, A] =
    this match {
      case Pure(f)          => f(a)
      case And(left, right) =>
        (left(a), right(a)) match {
          case (Right(a), Right(_)) => a.asRight
          case (Right(_), Left(e))  => e.asLeft
          case (Left(e), Right(_))  => e.asLeft
          case (Left(e1), Left(e2)) => (e1 |+| e2).asLeft
        }
    }
}

object CheckADT {
  final case class And[E, A](left: CheckADT[E, A], right: CheckADT[E, A]) extends CheckADT[E, A]

  final case class Pure[E, A](func: A => Either[E, A]) extends CheckADT[E, A]

  def pure[E, A](f: A => Either[E, A]): CheckADT[E, A] = Pure(f)

}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val a: CheckADT[List[String], Int] =
      CheckADT.pure {
        v =>
          if (v > 2) v.asRight
          else List ("Must be > 2").asLeft
      }

    val b: CheckADT[List[String], Int] =
      CheckADT.pure {
        v =>
          if (v < - 2) v.asRight
          else List ("Must be < -2").asLeft
      }

    val check: CheckADT[List[String], Int] = a and b
    println(check(5))
    println(check(-10))
  }
}
```

So what's wrong with my 'sc' file?

Comment: You are overshading `a` variable (or maybe even using it in pattern-matching to match `Right` value against `a`), maybe that confuses IDE/script in some contexts.

Comment: I was able to run your code in IDEA 2021.1.3 and Scala 2.13.6, it gave no compiler warnings. What versions of the compiler and IDEA are you using? Also Have you tried rebuilding the project or invaliding caches and restarting intelliJ?

Comment: PS: If you are using the latest version of **cats** replace all your implicit imports with just `import cats.syntax.all._`